# Can you heal outside of combat?

Tags: coin-crypt

I've been getting hurt, and the enemies on this floor attack so quickly that I don't really have time to heal using my coins, particularly if I don't get any heal coin draws for a few hands.

Is there some way I can heal outside of combat?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know, the only way to heal outside of battle is by using one of the Wishing Wells. They are pretty simple to use: the more money you donate to the well, the more you will be healed.

Unfortunately, the only other ways to heal seem to be in battle, though there are ways to increase the chances of getting healing coins. Donating money to [Sacagawea](http://coin-crypt.wikia.com/wiki/Sacagawea), for example, should increase the rate at which you will find many of the healing coins (including regeneration coins, coins that hit your enemy and heal you, among many others).

Alternatively, you can try your hand at buying items that improve your healing from a shop, or risk a bargain with one of the spirits to get some healing buffs (healing at the beginning of every level, or bonuses to healing in battle).

You could also choose one of the characters that has unique methods of healing. For example, the [Conquistador](http://coin-crypt.wikia.com/wiki/Coinquistador) heals 5 health at the beginning of every level (which can be further buffed at a cost from a spirit's blessing), but cannot heal in battle (use lots of shields, and try to avoid poisoning, since poison will drain your health). The [Vampire](http://coin-crypt.wikia.com/wiki/Vampire) is constantly losing health, but steals health after every attack (just watch out for Cardinals who block your life-stealing, and Zombies who can poison you a great deal).